# last.fm json call error

Tags: jquery, json, last.fm

the following code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.search&artist=megadeath&api_key=b5bd5e1d31bf4188a6bcd329c964f6f2&limit=5&format=json&callback=?',
        success : function(){
            console.log("slurped up data");
        },
        complete: function(){
            console.log("just completed the call");
        },
        error : function(){
            console.log("something stinks in Denmark");
        },
    });
```

throws an error. When I look at the REST call in the browser I see that it actually produces output, so I think the error pops up in the way the data is handled by jQuery. Have folks encountered this problem before? any suggestions on how to handle this issue?

Comment: We need to know what the error is.

Comment: what results are you seeing, also i take it "something stinks in denmakr "?

Comment: yup the error is caught and I see the denmark comment

Answer (score 2):

if you chop `&callback=?` off the end it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y44ZD/et

note how in the example on fiddle I get the error message with:

```
    error : function(e,d,f){
        alert(f);
    }
```

I was getting "unexpected token ?"

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

says:

> error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)Function
>
> A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives
>   three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a
>   string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional
>   exception object, if one occurred.

Your code would be:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.search&artist=megadeath&api_key=b5bd5e1d31bf4188a6bcd329c964f6f2&limit=5&format=json',
    success : function(){
        console.log("slurped up data");
    },
    complete: function(){
        console.log("just completed the call");
    },
    error : function(){
        console.log("something stinks in Denmark");
    },
});
```

EDIT (Question from comment): I would have to read the last.fm documentation but normally callbacks only need to be specified in the request when the remote server is going to contact your server with the answer. this technique is used for more secure communication (e.g. making a payment with an online payment processing company) when the data is return in response to your request its up to you how you process it e.g.:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    datatype:'json',
    url:'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.search&artist=megadeath&api_key=b5bd5e1d31bf4188a6bcd329c964f6f2&limit=5&format=json',
    success :
        function(data){
              $.each(data.results.artistmatches.artist, function(key, val) {
            $('body').append('<a href="'+val.url+'">'+val.name + '</a><br />');
        });

    },
    complete: function(){
        alert("just completed the call");
    },
    error : function(e,d,f){
        console.log(f);
    },
});
```

here is that example: http://jsfiddle.net/rS3p9/7/

(note if like me you are having trouble interpreting json tools like this help: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ thay format it nicely so you can see whats going on ;-)

EDIT: okay I just checked the docs:
http://www.last.fm/api/show?service=272

they dont mention a callback:

> limit (Optional) : The number of results to fetch per page. Defaults to 50.
>
> page (Optional) : The page number to fetch. Defaults to first page.
>
> artist (Required) : The artist name
>
> api_key (Required) : A Last.fm API key.

Comment: apologies in advance if this is a matter for another thread but don't I need &callback=? if I want to pass data to a function on success? I am still a bit hazy on how callback functions work, I guess.

Comment: nope dont think so ..sorry trying to give a good example 2 mins

Comment: updated the question with an example that lists possible matching artists as links

Comment: rock lobster! thank you so much for setting my brain somewhat straighter on this topic. much appreciated!

Comment: no probs, best thing to do is accept the answer (green tick under number at the answer title) and  if you think its informative upvote it (arrow above number).